# Python code for nesting and finding the second lowest based on the inputs

Tags: python

The question is - 'Given the names and grades for each student in a class of  students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

Note: If there are multiple students with the second lowest grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.'

This is my code-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        name_list = list(name)
        score_list = [score]
        sort_score = sorted(list(set(score_list)))
        second = sort_score[1]
        nest = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(name_list, score_list)]
        for x in nest:
            if x == second:
                print(x)
```

Can someone help me with this, I don't want an entirely new code, but few edits in my code as I have just started learning python

Comment: What do you think *list(name)* does?

Comment: To make the input names into a list...but I didn't realize 'append', further simply, [] can make items in a list